# Wait for message loop

Tags: c#, winapi, message-queue

I am writing some software in c# with win32 calls that searches for a window by caption.  When the window appears, my software sends various windows messages to it, to automate repetitive activity that I don't want to manually do myself.  What I've found is that some times the WM messages that get sent do not appear to get processed by the application.  My current theory is that my software discovers the window and starts sending windows messages before the applications message loop is actually created.

Is there a way to wait until the message loop is running?

Answer (score 1):

[Process.WaitForInputIdle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx) might be one solution.

> Causes the Process component to wait
>   indefinitely for the associated
>   process to enter an idle state. This
>   overload applies only to processes
>   with a user interface and, therefore,
>   a message loop.

Comment: WaitForInputIdle only waits once, on the first call.  If you use it subsequently, it just returns success right away.  I'll give it a shot, but not sure it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Do the window messages *never* get processed? Are you getting blocked by UIPI?

Comment: No blocking, and never processed.